# Is there a version of Dundas Maps by Microsoft?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, gis, dundas

I have a project which integrates Dundas Maps, which last I've heard is currently unsupported, and has been bought over by Microsoft a few years ago.

I am wondering if there is a Microsoft released library that was built off Dundas Maps.

I know Microsoft has released Microsoft Chart Controls for .NET 3.5 to replace Dundas Charting Tools, but I am not sure if there is a similar version for Dundas Maps. I need to use Dundas Maps for a seamless transition.

For mapping software, the closest I've found while Googling is Bing Maps, and that's not quite exactly what I'm looking for, since it does not seem to have a C# library.

Comment: Winforms or webforms?

Comment: Hi, will need one for webforms

Comment: You should user Microsoft Mappoint. It has an OCX control that you can use in winforms. I have used it in many applications and works well.

Comment: Hi I don't think it has a map for Australia? Looking through the pricings, it seems to only have NA or Europe edition. I found another one called Maptitude, but it might not be ideal because the GIS is a compiler/debugger on its own - I need it to be a user control that can be referenced in .NET web forms.

Comment: Oh i thought you need one for winforms, for webforms why not this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24468/Google-Maps-Control-for-ASP-NET-Part-1?

Comment: I found this one called Easy GIS.NET, it looks like it will do what I need it to do. Here's the demo for what the map section should do. If you change the drop down to different values, then hover over the states, you should get a numbered stat pop up as a tooltip. http://www.easygisdotnet.com/demos/Demo3.aspx

Comment: Yes, it is a good one. I have tried that in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps is what you are looking for. There are several different API's for Bing Maps. Several of them can be used in C#. If you are creating a WPF or WinForm application that take a look at the Bing Maps WPF control. If you are creating a web application then there is the bing Maps Silverlight and AJAX controls. You can fin documentation on the different API's here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx